# Is there a way to select from a Generic Inquiry in a BLC?

Tags: acumatica

I'm looking to use the results of a Generic Inquiry inside BLC logic.  I know I can use a web service call to a GI and put the results into an array - but can I do the same thing using some type of BQL call in a graph/graph extension?

Comment: Could you describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the results of a Generic Inquiry into an array in BLC code.  In other words, say I'm in a graph extention.  I have a button that executes code which contains logic to get the results from a Generic Inquiry and use those results to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

See below a tiny sample showing how to select records from a GI:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public PXAction<SOOrder> Test;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField]
    protected void test()
    {
        var dataGraph = PXGenericInqGrph.CreateInstance("GI000010");
        if (dataGraph != null)
        {
            var count = dataGraph.Views["Results"].SelectMulti().Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, Ruslan...  ;D

Comment: Is there a way to grab an array of the results?  I've tried several of the methods / properties provided (e.g.,DataGraph.Views["Results"].SelectMulti()[0], etc.) but none of them seem to return a dataset or array of the results.

Comment: Any ideas on this?